# How to call an async Task<ActionResult<>> from another method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following method and I want to call this from another method in the same controller.  I have tried Task.Run but I can't seem to get it to work.  This is .Net Core.

Here is the method I want to call:

```
[HttpGet("GetInfo")]
public async Task<ActionResult<InfoModel>> GetInfo()
  {
     InfoModel si = new InfoModel()
     //Do work
     return si
  }
```

I then want to call it in another API method (below)

```
[HttpPost("GetOtherInfo")]
public async Task<ActionResult<NewModel>> GetOtherInfo(RequestInfoModel req)
  {
     NewModel ret = new NewModel();
     //Do some work
     //Need some data from the GetInfo() method 
     InfoModel im1 = GetInfo();  //This does not work
     //Do work with im1
     return ret;
  }
```

I am looking for help on how to call GetInfo() from within GetOtherInfo().  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't do that. Either move that functionality into another method or class. That way it can be reused.

Comment: `GetInfo()` is meant to be called by the framework. That fact that it has to be called in addition to that is a violation of SRP/SoC and a code smell. This indicates that a refactor is needed.

Comment: Thanks Nkosi - I will refactor to keep the GetInfo() method but take the work out and put it in another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a controller action `GetInfo()` is meant to be called by the framework when satisfying requests.

That fact that it has to be called in addition to that is a violation of SRP/SoC and a code smell. This indicates that a refactor is needed.

Either move that functionality into another method or another class if needed external to just this controller. That way it can be reused as needed.

```
private Task<InfoModel> getInfoAsync() {
    InfoModel model = new InfoModel();

    //Do async work

    return model;
}

[HttpGet("GetInfo")]
public async Task<ActionResult<InfoModel>> GetInfo() {
    InfoModel model = await getInfoAsync();

    //and additional work needed specific to this request

    return model;
}

[HttpPost("GetOtherInfo")]
public async Task<ActionResult<NewModel>> GetOtherInfo(RequestInfoModel req) {
    NewModel ret = new NewModel();

    //Do some work

    //Need some info data
    InfoModel im1 = await getInfoAsync();

    //Do work with im1

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed - thank you very much for taking the time to do write it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your method is returning a `Task<X>`, you need to `await` the results.

```
[HttpPost("GetOtherInfo")]
public async Task<ActionResult<NewModel>> GetOtherInfo(RequestInfoModel req)
  {
     NewModel ret = new NewModel();
     //Do some work
     //Need some data from the GetInfo() method 
     InfoModel im1 = await GetInfo(); 
     //Do work with im1
     return ret;
  }
```

Note that it's usually a good idea to follow conventions and add the `Async` suffix to methods returning a `Task`.

ex: `GetInfoAsync()`

Comment: Thank you for the note on naming conventions, I will do that.  It does not matter if I am refactoring as Nkosi states above (which I am doing) but the issue I was having with just adding await is that the returns a Task<ActionResult<InfoModel>> and not just an InfoModel.  I think the "right" answer is to move the code into it's own method though.  Thank you!